# GNU screen session stops working

Tags: gnu-screen

I use screen to run a script which will run for several days (It will train some neural nets). In general it's working.

However, it appears that screen and all processes started in the screen session stops working after some time. This means the processes still exist but they seem to sleep. After reattaching with the screen session (`screen -r`) the processes continue.

Any idea why the processes take a break?

Comment: ask your sysadmin

Comment: Yes, ask your sysadmin. It may be that there is some sort of script running that will pause long-running jobs on the server that you're using. Make sure that you are using the resource in an appropriate way.

Comment: Could this be related to the stdout and (potentially) entering copy mode? I've found that when I look back over terminal output from a process that is still running, that process can sometimes sleep. Be sure that, if you're running it "interactively", that you're not in copy-mode. 

Perhaps when you reconnect the session, you have exited copy-mode, so it resumes?

Comment: Had this happen with `tmux` on a remote server (vps) a while ago. Usually they either pause the process like Kusalananda mentioned, or `kill` it directly...I found that in certain instance, trapping the process like so `trap process HUP` sometimes work. Best bet is to ask your sysadmin as the other mentioned if that doesn't work.